# Domain printers appear offline on non-domain PCs

Tags: domain, printing, windows-authentication

Our organization must be able to offer non-domain PC's printing facilities using our domain printserver and since Windows 7 was released, it seems that the Kerberos ticket/printing authentication simply runs out without letting the user re-authenticate as it did on Windows XP. When it happens the domain printers appears to be offline. If authentication is forced (i.e. opening the print share) the printers are again available.

How can I make this work without manual re-authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already sorted it out, but you have to create winthin your windows credential manager an entry for that mapping to the printserver.
Without any provided and windows was rebooted it will use the local account and therefor the installed network printers will be shown offline or not available.

So when you add the proper domain credential together with the right UNC path to the printserver and share, windows will use this to connect and the non domain laptop, will be able to use this network printer, even when reboot his system whatsoever.